# Return class object with member variable

Tags: c++, compilation

Why the function test() works even I'm not returning a Base class ? What happens with the compilation ? Can someone explain me ?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(){}
    Base(int val): _val(val){};
    ~Base(){};

Base test(int n){
    return (n);
}

int &operator *() { return (_val); };

private:
    int _val;

};


int main()
{
    Base base;
    Base a;

    a = base.test(42);
    std::cout << *a << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: The constructor `Base(int val)` is a converting constructor. `return (n);` is effectively shorthand for `return Base(n);` because it knows how to construct a `Base` out of an `int`.

Comment: The above comment is correct. You can mark the constructor as `explicit` to prevent the implicit conversion:

    `explicit Base(int val): _val(val){};`

Comment: Relevant reading as to why you might want to do this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060524-12/?p=31083

Comment: this is an example of a compiler trying to be helpful, but not really. This can be the cause of extremely confusing bugs, hence 'explicit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a constructor that takes in an `int`, and you declared that `test(int n)` should always return a `Base` class. The compiler knows that in order to create a `Base` object you need either nothing (default constructor) or an `int`, so it creates an object using the constructor that takes an `int` an returns that.

If you wanted to, you could be explicit about it and do something like the following and get the exact same behaviour:

```
Base test(int n){
    return Base(n);
}
```

In short, `n` is implicitly cast to a `Base` object, as you declared a constructor that requires only an `int`.